# Static files in Amazon S3 bucket - Django collectstatic error

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I am trying put my static files in one bucket into my Amazon S3 account
My configuration is the following:

- I've installed these packages:

`pip install django-storages-redux
pip install django-boto`

My `settings.py` file is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
         ...
    'storages',
         ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

#With this configuration, the static files (projects and applications) will stayed centralized in one directory
STATIC_ROOT = os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-2] + ['static-content'])

#Amazon S3 Storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
#DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = get_env_variable('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =  get_env_variable('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'neurorehabilitation-project'
```

When I execute `collectstatic` command, I get this message:

```
(nrb_dev)➜  neurorehabilitation_project git:(master) ✗ python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 107, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 321, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 234, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 431, in exists
    k = self.bucket.new_key(self._encode_name(name))
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 289, in bucket
    self._bucket = self._get_or_create_bucket(self.bucket_name)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 322, in _get_or_create_bucket
    return self.connection.get_bucket(name, validate=self.auto_create_bucket)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 278, in connection
    proxy_port=self.proxy_port
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 190, in __init__
    validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 977, in get_auth_handler
    ready_handlers.append(handler(host, config, provider))
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 134, in __init__
    HmacKeys.__init__(self, host, config, provider)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.update_provider(provider)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 138, in update_provider
    super(HmacAuthV1Handler, self).update_provider(provider)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 75, in update_provider
    self._hmac = hmac.new(self._provider.secret_key.encode('utf-8'),
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
(nrb_dev)➜  neurorehabilitation_project git:(master) ✗
```

What items or configurations should I take in account for send my static files to Amazon S3?

I am working with python3.4 and Django 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing commas from the following settings. The trailing commas mean that Python treats them as tuples rather than strings.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = get_env_variable('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =  get_env_variable('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, I have my files into bucket. :D. I cannot see my media files (uploads by the user). I guess that I am not tell to Django that upload them How to can I upload my media files to Amazon S3?  In this link https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/6 talk about it, I've follow the instructions ...

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question about uploading media files, rather than asking in the comments.

Comment: I've writing the question in an other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604034/putting-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3-bucket-media-files just in case. Thanks